# When to save Singleton data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

So I'm using a global singleton to manage my app's data, that I need to be persistent throughout app launches. Thus, I'm writing the singleton's data to a file, and reading them in the init method.

My questions is when to save the singleton back to the file. Right now whenever I make any change to my singleton, I also call `.saveData()` to save them, but this means I overwrite a file a lot more than I need to.

I'm trying to prevent any data loss due to my app's termination and I was thinking of saving my data inside `applicationWillResignActive` or `applicationDidEnterBackground`, instead of saving every time I make a change. Another idea that came to me while reading the swift iBook is to actually call `saveData` in my singleton's `deinit {}`, but I'm not sure if a destructor is suited for the job of writing everything to a file before destroying the object.

Is any of the above methods guaranteed to save my data the day I want it? (Let's assume that my app does not crash, since if it does it's understandable that some data will be lost)

What is the best time to call my `saveData()` method?

P.S.: In the future I'll use CoreData for saving my data instead of a file, but for now I need a my data up and running to put the rest of the app (UI, animations, networking etc) together.

Comment: As long as it it's not too big, you could use NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a combination of `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate`.

`applicationWillTerminate` - This is your 'goto' method for doing clean up/saving before the app is terminated. However, it won't trigger if the app was suspended before termination.

`applicationDidEnterBackground` - Because the previous method doesn't trigger if the application process is suspended first, you'll want to trigger on background as well because the application will enter background before suspension (the case where `applicationWillTerminate` alone would be insufficient)

Comment: Thank you! I'm using applicationDidEnterBackground since there is no guarantee that applicationWillTerminate will be called. Is it a bad practise writing files when applicationDidEnterBackground is called, or that is the iOS way to go?